# Cocoapod 0.38.0 and AFNetworking 2.5 AF_APP_EXTENSIONS compilation error

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

My project has 9 targets :

```
- Prod
- Prod_app_extension_1
- Prod_app_extension_2
- Beta 
- Beta_app_extension_1
- Beta_app_extension_2
- Dev
- Dev_app_extension_2
- Dev_app_extension_2
```

I'm using 0.38.2 cocoapod version and 2.5.4 AFNetworking.

I'm trying to use AFNetworking with cocoapod but I get the *AF_APP_EXTENSIONS* error while compiling. After searching for the solution on the web, I understand the problem and found that defining the 'preprocessor macros' *AF_APP_EXTENSIONS* can fix the problem.

But here is the struggle : By default, *AF_APP_EXTENSIONS* is correctly added into my 6 app_extensions. In the other hand, when I navigate through my Pods target, **each Pods are separated** :

```
- NSDate+TimeAgo 
- AFNetworking
- iRate
- AppUtils
- Prod
- Prod_app_extension_1
- Prod_app_extension_2
- Beta 
- Beta_app_extension_1
- Beta_app_extension_2
- Dev
- Dev_app_extension_2
- Dev_app_extension_2
```

In another project I made, all pods are generated this way :

```
- Prod
- Pods-Prod-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Prod-AFNetworking
- Pods-Prod-iRate
- Pods-Prod-AppUtils

- Prod_app_extension_1
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_1-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_1-AFNetworking
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_1-iRate

- Prod_app_extension_2
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_2-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_2-AFNetworking
- Pods-Prod_app_extension_2-iRate

- Beta
- Pods-Beta-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Beta-AFNetworking
- Pods-Beta-iRate
- Pods-Beta-AppUtils 

- Beta_app_extension_1
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_1-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_1-AFNetworking
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_1-iRate

- Beta_app_extension_2
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_2-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_2-AFNetworking
- Pods-Beta_app_extension_2-iRate

- Dev
- Pods-Dev-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Dev-AFNetworking
- Pods-Dev-iRate
- Pods-Dev-AppUtils 

- Dev_app_extension_1
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_1-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_1-AFNetworking
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_1-iRate

- Dev_app_extension_2
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_2-NSDate+TimeAgo
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_2-AFNetworking
- Pods-Dev_app_extension_2-iRate
```

I think this is why my 'preprocessor macros' *AF_APP_EXTENSIONS* isn't define into the 'AFNetworking' Pods target.

Here is my Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

xcodeproj 'myProj.xcodeproj'


def generic_pods
    pod 'NSDate+TimeAgo'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
end

def app_pods
    pod 'iRate'
    pod 'AppUtils',
end



target "Prod" do
    generic_pods
    app_pods
end

target "Prod_app_extension_1" do
    generic_pods
end

target "Prod_app_extension_2" do
    generic_pods
end

target "Beta" do
    generic_pods
    app_pods
end

target "Beta_app_extension_1" do
    generic_pods
end

target "Beta_app_extension_2" do
    generic_pods
end

target "Dev" do
    generic_pods
    app_pods
end

target "Dev_app_extension_1" do
    generic_pods
end

target "Dev_app_extension_2" do
    generic_pods
end
```

I don't know what the problem is, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Do you use Swift or Objective C? I've seen you try to support iOS7. If that's true and you're in Swift you are going to face problems regarding dynamic frameworks. Do you use Objective C?

Comment: No, my main project is in Objective-C. Only few components are in Swift.

Comment: Hope someone with more objective-C experiences will show up since I can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since 0.38.0 cocoapod version, pod target are De-duplicate**. It means, instead of bulding an AFNetworking for each of your project target ('Pods-MyApp-AFNetworking', 'Pods-MyExtension-AFNetworking', ...) only one AFNetworking pod target is generated ('Pods-AFNetworking').

**AFNetworking require 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS' flag into the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS** to compile when added to app-extensions.

Until the 0.37.2 cocoapod version, it was possible to add the flag from your project Podfile by adding a post-install routine :

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ar.include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1']
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Unfortunatly, with the De-duplicate cocoapod feature, it's no longer possible to add the AF_APP_EXTENSIONS flag to the app extention pod targets separately.

The only way I found is to compile is to create a file : **~/.cocoapods/config.yaml** (not present by default when you use cocoapod, you can create it with the terminal) with this content :

```
deduplicate_targets: false
```

This way, pods aren't not de-duplicated and you can post-install add the AF_APP_EXTENSIONS into your app extensions GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS.

I just hope they will found a good way to prevent this problem.

references :

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#highlighted-enhancement-that-needs-testing => cocoapod change log

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3794 => discussed issue